# SSIS Error code 0x80004005

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

We have packages which are deploying data between two servers and the packages are placed in file system share of the destination server. SQL Server version 2008r2
The package succeeds at one time and fails at the other time on same day run.

Error details:

```
Error: 2014-01-28 16:03:14.30
   Code: 0xC0202009
   Source: All Active customers Connection manager "SourceConnectionOLEDB"
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Client unable to establish connection due to prelogin failure".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Client unable to establish connection".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Client unable to establish connection because an error was encountered during handshakes before login. Common causes include client attempting to connect to an unsupported version of SQL Server, server too busy to accept new connections or a resource limitation (memory or maximum allowed connections) on the server.".
End Error
Error: 2014-01-28 16:03:14.30
   Code: 0xC020801C
   Source: Data Flow Task 1 Source - daily_customer_details[1]
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "SourceConnectionOLEDB" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
End Error
```

Comment: What is the package `protection` level ?

Comment: EncryptAllwithpassword

Comment: Is there anything in the server event logs or the SQL Server logs on the SQL Server that you are trying to connect to? You could also try running Profiler on the server that you are failing to connect to and try and capture the issue. Here is another article that might be worth reading http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/04/08/understanding-connection-forcibly-closed-by-remote-host-errors-caused-by-toe-chimney.aspx You either will or won't see an indication in the SQL Error log that it forcibly closed the connection. This indicates whether its a SQL problem or a network problem

Comment: I don’t see anything in the logs. We are facing this issue intermittently. We checked with the server team they say no patch works or any issue in the server. I asked them to restart the server or an instance; they say that can’t be done as it is used by many other teams.

Comment: can anyone help me out with this error message